# Issue with UTL_MAIL.SEND_ATTACH_RAW function sending mail with attachment using EDB postgres

Tags: enterprisedb

I am using the function `SEND_ATTACH_RAW` to send a mail with an attachment:

```
UTL_MAIL.SEND_ATTACH_RAW( 
    sender=>v_sender,
    recipients=>v_recipients,
    cc=>NULL,
    bcc=>NULL,
    subject=>'foto',
    message=> 'foto de prueba',
    mime_type=> 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii',
    priority=>3,
    attachment=>import_binary_file('/tmp/IMG_20220127_173051147.jpg'),--this function load binary as bytea
    att_inline=>TRUE, 
    att_mime_type=>'image/jpg',
    att_filename=>'test.jpg');
```

And work well, but the attachment file name that I receive is named 'noname', please can you help to solve this issue with the name,  I would like to receive the `att_filename` value

Version:

```
 PostgreSQL 14.2 (EnterpriseDB Advanced Server 14.2.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit
```

Comment: try using att_inline =>   FALSE

Comment: Thanks, work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the benefit of all, I have posted it as a solution. Try using

```
 att_inline => FALSE
```

I have suggested this solution based on the oracle MOS document below which will be applicable to EDB Postgres as well.

How to Send Any Type of Attachment with UTL_MAIL [(Doc ID 946811.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/946811_1.html)